# Converting to binary - getting IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, bluej

Below is some code I'm working on, I thought I'd make myself a binary calculator to make my life slightly easier. However, when I run it, I get an error telling me that there is a `Java.lang.StringIndexOutofBoundsException`. I don't really know how to fix it, because as far as I can tell, I've done everything correctly:

```
private static void ten()
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What number would you like to convert to binary?");
    System.out.print("Enter the integer here:  ");
    int x = scan.nextInt();

    String bon = Integer.toString(x , 2);

    int myArrays [ ] = new int [ 7 ];

    myArrays[0] = bon.charAt(0); 
    myArrays[1] = bon.charAt(1); 
    myArrays[2] = bon.charAt(2); 
    myArrays[3] = bon.charAt(3); 
    myArrays[4] = bon.charAt(4); 
    myArrays[5] = bon.charAt(5); 
    myArrays[6] = bon.charAt(6); 
    myArrays[7] = bon.charAt(7); 

    for (int i = 0; i < myArrays.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(myArrays [ i ] + " ");
        int count = 0;
        count++;
        if (count == 10) {
            System.out.println();
            count = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to perform basic debugging:  Read the stack trace of your exception, as it tells you exactly which line is causing the problem.  Then, add some `System.out.println` statements *before* that line, so you can see both your String and the index you're trying to access.

Comment: I'm slightly confused here. Some people are saying that I should increase my array by one, and others say I should decrease my array by one. Which one do I do?

Comment: Get rid of the array altogether.

Comment: and debug your own code, which should have been the first thing you should have done before coming here

Comment: I've tried debugging my code, and I've come across a different problem entirely.  My array, should all eight integers of the array be filled, prints out "49" eight times. I assumed that the array would be printed, not something else. But it makes sense now, I'll try to do it by myself. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the number you enter, the length of the binary string will vary. If you enter 0 or 1, you'll get "0" or "1". But your code assumes your number has 8 bits. This means that it will only work if the eighth bit is set.

It looks like you are trying to print the bits separated by spaces, followed by a new line. It would be better to use a more direct approach:

```
String b = Integer.toString(x, 2);
for (int idx = 0; idx < b.length(); ++idx) {
  System.out.print(b.charAt(idx));
  System.out.print(' ');
}
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you have an array of size 7 which only gives you 0-6 but you make a call to array[7] so increase your array size by one

Comment: I thought arrays started at element "0"?

Comment: You are correct about the array size (should be array[8]). However, that is not where he is getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException - it is at the line of code:    myArrays[3] = bon.charAt(3);

Answer (score 0):

myArrays is a 7 elements len array, if you do operations from 0 to 7 you are going outside the limit..

try from 0 to 6!

Answer (score 0):

Your array size needs to be larger...
`int myArrays [ ] = new int [ 8 ];`

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to note in your code:

**1.**

```
int myArrays [] = new int [7];
```

Should be changed to:

```
int myArrays [] = new int [8];
```

**2.**

You call `bon.charAt()` without checking that your variable `bon` has enough characters.

Answer (score 0):

Java.lang.StringIndexOutofBoundsException Pretty much indicates string's length is less than the index. You should consider the length. Also there are other Out of bounds in arrays that others mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Replace these 2 lines:

```
String bon = Integer.toString(x , 2);
int myArrays [ ] = new int [ 7 ];
```

With these lines (1 just to display the initial value):

```
String byteString = Integer.toBinaryString(x & 0xFF);
byteString = String.format("%8s", byteString).replace(' ', '0');
int[] myArrays = new int[8];
System.out.println("(" + byteString  + ")");
```